# On mouseover cursor changes to button form

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need some help with my d3.js. Could someone help me in implementing a feature that on mouse over your cursor turns into the "click" cursor form? For example when you click hover over a button on stack overflow the cursor changes.

```
.on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .style("fill", "#3b6887");

    })
```

Comment: Use the CSS rule `cursor: pointer` on whatever you are targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the different cursors available you can use [cursor CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Try the following

```
.on('mouseover', function() {
    d3.select(this)
        .style('fill', '#3b6887')
        .style('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```